# DOORS DXL: How to place the DXL Code in Trigger?

Tags: ibm-doors

I want to apply a persistant pre trigger on a specific attribute in Relational DOORS with DXL.
The Declaration follows the below syntax:

`Trigger trigger(string name, l, t, e, int p, string dxl)`

where:

l - level: project, module, object, module

t - type: pre or post

e - event: open, read, close, save, modifiy or sync

The Trigger should insert to the current modified Object the username and the current date in front of the text (e.g. 2021-08-06 Max: 'Text from user')

My current Code:
`trigger("Triggername", module->"specificMod"->attribute->"specificAttr", pre, modify, 10, 'DXL Code')`

The DXL Reference Manual implements the Code with #include but every user uses an another path for the trigger library.

There is already an example code in the DXL library for saving the view before closing the Module:

```
trigger(u (NLS_(":autoSaveView")), module->formal, pre, close, 10,
        (NLS_("if (doorsname == \"")) u (NLS_("\" && confirm \"Save current view?\") save view \"")) u (NLS_("-autoSaved\"")))
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Script placement on a shared file server? Code escapes?

Comment: The problem is how to place a (String) function in the trigger function. I`m a beginner in DXL so if you have some tips it would be great to hear.